# Embed slides at a later point in the same presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to embed (for example, with `\includegraphics{}`) in the last slide of my beamer presentation four miniatures of the most significant slides of the same presentation, in order to recall important content, [like this blog post suggests](http://andreas-zeller.blogspot.it/2013/10/summarizing-your-presentation-with.html).

The final result would look like this:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: You can use `\againframe{label}`. Have a look at section 11.2 of the beamer user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary workaround:

1. compile the presentation with the final slide empty (without miniatures) (`out.pdf`)
2. copy (or move) the resulting pdf file to a new position: `out.pdf` -> `dummy.pdf`
3. use `dummy.pdf` to import the desired slides with `\includegraphics[page=<n>, width=<w>]{dummy.pdf}`

Answer (score 5):

Reusing frames can be achieved with the `\againframe` command.

You have to use a `label=labelname` statement as optional argument to the `frame` environment.
Later on, it's possible to recall this frame with `\againframe{labelname}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=first]{My first frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=second]{My second frame}

\end{frame}

\againframe{first}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, not excactly what I'm looking for, though. I updated and clarified the question, as I managed to find the blog post that gave me the idea.